# What is approach to overlap one element above another in XAML when they get/lost focus?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two `DockPanel` elements:

```xml
<DockPanel Margin="10">
    <TextBlock Text="+ Add new note" />
</DockPanel>
```

```xml
<DockPanel Margin="10">
    <ComboBox>
        <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <Button Content="Add Note" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0" Padding="10,0" />
    <TextBox Margin="10,0"  />
</DockPanel>
```

I want to get follow result: once I click on first `DockPanel`, it must be hidden and second one is showed instead. After I click on button `Add Note`, second `DockPanel` must be hidden and first one must be appeared again.

I wonder an approach how to make it but don't know where to begin.

I'm appreciate for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

A rough solution (no MVVM base) might be the following:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel Margin="10" x:Name="EditDP" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <ComboBox>
            <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <Button Content="Add Note" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Margin="0" Padding="10,0" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
        <TextBox Margin="10,0"  />
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel x:Name="MainDP" Margin="10" MouseLeftButtonDown="UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown">
        <TextBlock Text="+ Add new note" />
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MainDP.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        this.EditDP.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MainDP.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this.EditDP.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve it by XAML only?

Comment: @AceLightning: you didn't mention you needed all the code in XAML. Moreover, why you need to code it on XAML only?

Comment: I'd like to keep logic of UI only in XAML as much as possible. XAML-solutions often look more elegant and faster (IMHO)

Answer (score -1):

Bind the `Visibility` property of both the dockpanels to the same boolean and use `InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter` / `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` on each of them.

This way when you flip the boolean using either the click event on the first Dock panel or the button click on the second panel, the two panels will alternatively show up